# MarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL 1398079745 / Could find classes

Tags: java, jsf, netbeans, corba

we did a cleanbuild in netbeans, checked the jdk version and deployed everything at the server but still got the following error. Can somebody help?

> javax.servlet.ServletException: #{RegistrationController.register}:
>   javax.ejb.EJBException: nested exception is:
>   java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL 1398079745 Maybe; nested
>   exception is:  org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: ----------BEGIN server-side
>   stack trace---------- org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL:  vmcid: SUN  minor code:
>   257 completed: at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.couldNotFindClass(ORBUtilSystemException.java:9679)
>
> at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.couldNotFindClass(ORBUtilSystemException.java:9694)
>
> at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1042)
>
> at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:896)
>
> ...

Answer (score 0):

Normally Corba Marshal errors are related to the IDL of the Corba object and the generated stubs not matching up with the actual implemented method signature of the Corba object itself.

Also, make sure you have all of the normal Corba related jars referenced that you need for your Corba implementation.

You could also post your client and server code as well as the IDL you are using.